# TeXcenter project or LaTeX document

Tags: bibtex, texniccenter

BibTex is not compiling Bibliography it keeps on saying

> "I didn't find entry in the database"

but entries are there I m not sure if there is a problem with the path of installation.

Thanks for the reply. May be thats where my problem in How do I configure in the first place. I have entries in a folder I named `Mybib.bib`. and my document has the following before `\end{document}`

```
\bibliographystyle{alphaurl} \bibliography{Mybib}
\end {document}
```

After running pdf. the bibliography does not come up. instead it says

> "I didn't find entry in the database"

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please explain better your problem?  You are using the editor TeXnicCenter? Is that editor proper configured? Can you show us the configuration with an screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you call with for example `\cite{test}` an bib entry that is not included in your bib file. Then I think you see something like the following screenshot:

[image]

Please have a look into this MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \cite{test} % <============================================ comment
%This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}. % <== uncomment 
%\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys % <================== uncomment

\bibliographystyle{alphaurl} % alphaurl unsrt
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Please compile it **three times** for example with TeXnicCenters `LaTeX -> Pdf` to see the shown error message in the screenshot because I have no bib entry test in the included bib file.  No please comment line `\cite{test}` and **uncomment** the two following lines.  Then you cites two bib entrys.  `\nocite{*}` I have only added to show you how to test **all** bib entrys of your bib file.

Make sure, that in your output profile for TeXnicCenter the call of BiBTeX is configured like this:

[image]

Comment: It finally worked. Great Job guys. Thank you.

Comment: @Sibanda Well then please consider to accept my answer and upvote it, when you have earned more reputation. That is the way here to thank you for help :-)